# Delete entity in google datastore in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I want to delete/modify an entity in the google cloud datastore based on an email.

```
email = 'john@gmail.com'
query = client.query('email', '=', email)
# delete this entity if it exists??
```

Now that I have this query, how can I go about deleting this entity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
next_entity = query.fetch()
client.delete(next_entity.key)
```

If you're only deleting the entity and don't need anything other than the key, consider doing a `keys_only` query to avoid reading data you don't care about.